# Why does my clear:both not work when using CSS Selectors

Tags: html, css

I have a few HTML elements, which has a background color. I now added a float element and my background has gone. I understand why, and I know how to fix it (it's made very clear stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best/1633170 ) but my layout is slightly different.

```
<footer>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<p>Words<br /> And more words</p>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer {
    background:#ccc;
}

footer p { 
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
}

footer:after {
    content:'';
    display:table;
    clear: both;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyNnk/256/)

Why does this work? I'm not clearing anything after the footer!

Comment: `overflow: hidden` on the footer would work too and doesn't require the :after trick. Not useful all the time if you need another overflow value but works in most cases and much cleaner.

Comment: Your posted code doesn't match the fiddle demo, you've used `footer:after` in the fiddle which works as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: The `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements apply before and after the _content_ of the selected elements, not before and after the elements themselves. That's why this code works. You can imagine the structure to be something like: `<footer> ::before <p>blah blah content</p> ::after </footer>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set overflow: auto for footer.

```
footer { 
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

That will catch the floats.

http://jsfiddle.net/EyNnk/254/

**UPDATE:**

If you check your HTML output with a developer tool you can see that:

```
footer > p:after { content: ''; clear: both; }
```

results in following structure:

```
<p>Words<br> And more words::after</p>
```

That shows, that the pseudo-element ::after is **inside** of the tag, not behind it. That's why your code didn't work, you were clearing all floats inside of the p-tag.

So the solution to your question is:

```
footer:after { content: ''; clear: both; }
```

Which will include ::after in footer and so clear all floats **inside** your footer.

Comment: IMO the question is not about how to clear the float, but about **why** `footer:after` works while `footer :after` doesn't.

Comment: @Hashem Qolami I changed my answer, is this better?

Answer (score 1):

You should append the pseudo element to the footer itself **not to its descendants** by `footer :after` such as `<p>` elements (by `footer p:after`):

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/EyNnk/253/)**

```css
footer:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

This creates a pseudo element as the **last-child** of the `footer` which clears the float.

Again, `footer :after` is an equivalent of `footer *:after` which adds the `:after` pseudo element to **all descendants** of the `footer` rather than to the element itself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I realised quite quickly this was the answer, but I updated my question slightly to why. I'm not clearing anything after the footer... Everything is occuring within the footer element +1

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Please note that `footer :after` won't work also, Just updated the answer to explain the reason.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions As I noted `::after` pseudo-element *This creates a pseudo element as the last-child of the footer*; Not after the element itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
footer p:after {
```

`:after` is inserting after content of element. so It's mean `clear` after content of `p` just before tag close.

So, you suppose to use

```
footer:after {
```

To clear before closing `footer`.

Comment: I'm lost although I'm sure your right, but, you're saying the after tag closes before the end of the tag... Is that right?

Comment: `:after` is not really a TAG. It's just a generated content to insert inside a tag. http://jsfiddle.net/76kw5mk2/ check this you will see how `:before` and `:after` works.